# What is the difference between these two vector statements?

Tags: c++

[!!Correction made to the second code!!]

```
vector<int> a;
vector<int>*p = &a;
```

and

```
vector<int>*b = new vector<int>();
```

I know that in first scenario, a is on stack and in second b is on heap. But, are there any other differences? Like memory consumed etc.

Comment: Just like to point out that automatic allocation does not require stack allocation. If you ever use a global vector, it will not necessarily be on the stack, but probably resides in some special memory for automatically allocated variable. Also if the vector is a class member, it's location depends on where the instance of the class resides.

Comment: One more query here: How much memory does "vector<int> a" allocate?
Is that compiler dependent?

Comment: @Ken: a global vector isn't an automatic, so what does its location (on the stack or otherwise) have to do with the location of automatics? It's true that the standard doesn't specify a stack for automatic variables, but it specifies enough behavior that wherever automatics are stored starts to look a lot like a stack. But an implementer could in principle allocate stack frames from a mark-sweep garbage collector or something, if they really wanted to. And just from that code snippet we can't tell whether `a` is an automatic or not.

Comment: I believe that the default capacity of a vector is dependent on the which implementation of the STL you are using. The only guarantee is that the vector has a size of zero.

Comment: @Steve: Yes that's true. Is there a phrase in C++ which refers to any non-dynamic allocation of the form `Type a;`?

Comment: @Ken: Variable. Although that also applies to `const Type a;`, so you're never far from possible confusion: "How can a *variable* be *constant*?", "It just can, alright!". And it applies to definitions with initializers, but I don't think you were intending to exclude those, were you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes vector b is allocated on the heap and vector a is on the stack (assuming the code is in the scope of a method) along with a 4 byte pointer also on the stack. Other differences in memory consumed would depend on the memory manager and how it allocates blocks and any internal bookkeeping required for the heap.

Comment: The first sentence of this answer is not correct, as explained in Martin's excellent answer.

Comment: It should also be observed that both vectors will keep the contained `int`s in the heap,  The differences are where the vector keeps it pointers to the 'int's and other meta-information.  For 32-bit MSVC2010 in release with _SECURE_SCL=0, a vector is 12 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

> I know that in first scenario, a is on stack and in second b is on heap.

Both parts of that statement are wrong.
Mostly because the terms stack/heap are useless in describing C++ objects.

```
 vector<int>   a;
```

This is an `automatic storage duration object`. More commonly referred to as an `automatic` object.

It is created on first use and destroyed when it goes out of scope. The definition of scope depends on context. If you are in a function it is placed on the stack and destroyed when the function exists. If it is a member of an object then it is created with the object and destroyed with the object (in this case the object could be on the heap or stack).

Conversely:

```
vector<int>*   p = &a;
```

This is a pointer to an object. What it points to depends. In this case you are making it point at an automatic object (which as described above could be on the stack or heap).

Finally:

```
vector<int>*   q = new vector<int>();
```

This is a pointer to an object of `dynamic storage duration`. This means it is created with new and must be manually destroyed (Which is also why you never create RAW pointers, they are always wrapped in smart pointers (please read a book)). If this object is on the stack or heap depends on a lot of things as the language allows you override the default behavior (in a simple naive way you can think of it as being on the heap (but it is best to just forget the concept of heap and stack as they don't apply to C++).

It is best to think of object belonging to one of four categories:

- Static storage duration objects

  - Global variables (and a few other things)
  - You can think of these (until you know more) as created before main destroyed after main
- Thread Storage duration objects

  - Globals associated with a thread.
  - You can think of these as created with the thread destroyed after the thread
- Automatic Storage duration objects

  - Nearly all other objects
  - These are created when first encountered.
  - Destroyed when they go out of scope.
  - Scope depends on context.
- Dynamic storage duration objects

  - Objects allocated with new and de-allocated with delete.
  - Objects that should be contained in smart pointers or containers

Comment: Smart pointers aren't all they're cracked up to be. They can be abused as much as raw pointers.

Comment: "This is an aromatic storage duration "  he he :-)

Comment: I think you have things reversed - in a simple naive way you can think of automatics on the stack and dynamically-allocated objects on the heap, but you've written the opposite.

Comment: It looks like that "If you are in a function it is placed on the heap" is wrong. Could you make your answer more comprehensive? I've thought that all automatic objects are allocated on stack.

Comment: @George - Fixed the typos. We'll blame aromatic on the spell checker. Does "interesting" things sometimes. :-)

Comment: @Bo Persson: May be it was on purpose! because they are NOT a code smell they are the opposite of a bad smell and thus a good code smell or aromatic code :-)

Answer (score 2):

Both vectors will allocate the memory for their elements on the heap.
The main difference is the lifetime of your vector object. In the first case, it's on the stack and will be destroyed at the end of its scope.

In the second case, the vector will remain in memory until you call delete q.

Answer (score 1):

#### Original question:

You are asking, what is the difference between

```
vector<int> a;
vector<int>*p = &a
```

and

```
vector<int> b;
vector<int>* q=&b;
```

In both cases you have a vector, and you declare a pointer which is initialized to point to the vector. That extra indirection is usually not a good idea.

In the declaration of `p` you forgot the final semicolon, while in the declaration of `q` you didn't forget that.

That's all.

#### Second variant of question:

You are asking, what is the difference between

```
vector<int> a;
vector<int>*p = &a
```

and

```
vector<int>* q= new vector<int>();
```

In the first cases you have a vector, and you declare a pointer which is initialized to point to the vector. That extra indirection is usually not a good idea.

In the second case you declare a pointer to a vector and initialize it to point to a zero-size vector allocated via `new`. That's not a good idea ever. A vector does the memory management for you, which is much of the point: just Say No to that alluring `new`.

That's all.

---

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: I was just wondering that - I guess they downvoted based on your original answer which no longer made sense after the OP edited? I've +1'ed for parity :-)

Comment: No downvote from me because I agree that line of code is never a good idea, *but* it's not necessarily a bad idea to have a pointer to a dynamically-allocated vector, if different bits of code all interact with the same vector. It's just a bad idea to initialize it from `new`, since `new` demands some RAII to manage it. The correct place to obtain the raw pointer is `operator->` of a smart pointer ;-)

Comment: @Steve Jessop Getting a raw pointer from the `operator->` of a smart pointer counts as obfuscation to me.  Generally, if you need raw pointers to something, it shouldn't be managed by smart pointers anyway.  (But then, very few things should be managed by smart pointers.)  And if you need RAII to manage something, it probably shouldn't be allocated on the heap to begin with.

Comment: @James: sorry, that was tongue-in-cheek. I meant that the implementation will find the raw pointer for itself when you use `->` with the smart pointer. As for whether most RAII-managed objects are heap-allocated or not: that depends on the program and your exact definition of RAII. I think all dynamically-allocated objects should be RAII-managed, and there should be as few of them as possible, so "probably" is a question of how many *other* RAII-managed things you have knocking about: locks or whatever.

Comment: @Steve Jessop If you're using RAII, what's the point of heap allocations?  One of the principle reasons for allocating on the heap is because the lifetime of the object doesn't correspond to the lifetime of a local variable, so RAII doesn't really work either.

Comment: @Steve Jessop In other words, replacing deterministic lifetime with random lifetime.  **Most** objects you would dynamically allocate have specific lifetime requirements, and random lifetime is unacceptable.  Generally, `shared_ptr` is useful when the dynamic allocation is used only because copy is too expensive (and you can live with reference semantics), or in some cases, for short lived polymorphic objects, with no real behavior.  (In both cases, of course, true garbage collection would be preferable.  But we don't always have it available in C++.)

Comment: @James: yes, mark-sweep garbage collection in general is preferable to reference-counted garbage collection because it's easier to use, no need to worry about reference loops. But I don't really know what we're arguing about -- do you actually disagree with anything I've said, or are you just trying to instill readers with a healthy FUD about dynamic allocation, just in case they think that because I'm talking about it as if it's not terrifying, they should feel free to use it willy-nilly? Certainly I agree that objects with scoped lifetime should be preferred, they're easier to reason with.

Comment: @Steve Jessop I definitely disagree with the idea that you should use smart pointers for every bit of dynamically allocated memory.  One of the most frequent reasons for using dynamic allocation is that the object has a very determined lifetime (often ending with a `delete this` in the object itself); smart pointers aren't appropriate for such objects.

Comment: @James: OK, I don't think I've ever written code in that style, with an object that deletes itself soon after creation. It doesn't sound very safe -- what if the line before `delete this` throws an exception? -- but with sufficient nothrow guarantees I see that it would work. There may be other special cases too, for example if I'm implementing a container like vector then I might not use a smart pointer for the data, especially since in the case of vector you need to run destructors, via the allocator, on some but not all of the contents. I could separate concerns, but don't always bother.

Comment: ... but really that's because "vector" already is a RAII class, it just happens to do more than simply manage the resource. If I were to write a helper class for it that just did the resource management, then that helper class would become a kind of smart pointer, and I would be following my own rule.

Comment: @Steve Jessop The `delete this` isn't necessarily "soon" after creation; I've worked on applications where it was months, or even years later.  And if the function throws an exception before the `delete this`, then obviously, the object won't be deleted, and the request leading to its deletion (and possibly other things) will fail.  (As for `vector` being an RAII class, that depends on your point of view.  As a user, usually, I think of it more as a collection of values, and ignore the internals.  But if I need a buffer with a raw pointer, I'll use vector as an RAII class for it.)

Answer (score 0):

p and q are just pointers to the vector, which is initialized on the stack.

It should hold only 4 bytes on most platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Err, both p and q are pointers to vectors, both being pointed to the address of a and b respectively. They are in essence the same, but I'd probably be mad at someone formatting like the second example. ;)

It's just a slight tweak in syntax spacing (and a missing semi-colon on the second line of the first vector pair.).

Answer (score 0):

q is a pointer to object b which is on the stack. A pointer object is just an address( a number) while b is a vector instance

Comment: b does not need to be on the stack. It could just as easily be on the heap.